# capture submit event with dynamically added content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, submit

I am building a sort of page builder where the user can add blocks to the page and then save the layout. I have encountered a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have a form that is dynamically added to the page with JavaScript containing a file input as so:

```
<form class="upload " action="" method="post">
    <input id="" type="file" class="fill" name="upload">
    <img src="/admin/img/default.png" alt="">
</form>
```

After adding the content I call the following function to add event listeners. `$el` corresponds to the file input.

```
function changeListen($el){
    $el.addEventListener('change', function(){
        $el.parentElement.submit();
    });
    $el.parentElement.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        // call Ajax request...
    });
}
```

I want to be able to update the database with an Ajax request when an image is selected, therefore I submit the form within the `change` event, so far so good, but for some reason the `submit` event is not taken into account and the page reloads. Any solutions or workaround appreciated, preferably not jQuery.

Comment: maybe e.preventDefault() ? It should be called :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `onsubmit` event in HTML, you can call javascript function this way and do ajax calls.

Javascript sample

```
<script>
function doSomething() {
    alert('Hello, World');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

HTML Sample

```
<form onsubmit="return doSomething();">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

EDIT: return false in javascript so `?` does not appear in URI after clicked

Comment: No joy, the onsubmit is being ignored too. also tried using onsubmit="alert()" and onsubmit="return false" with no results.